# I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Telethon' when running a python script using the Telethon library (MacOS)

Tags: python, homebrew, telethon

I tried to run the code `python3 /Users/x/Documents/TLCounter-master/src/TLCounter.py`
I checked to make sure Telethon is there by

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which has Telethon==0.19.1.6 inside. (Returned Requirement already satisfied so it shouldn't be the case)
What else could be causing the problem?

I tried to uninstall and reinstall python with **brew**, but it didn't seem to fix the problem. also tried to reinstall Telethon, no results.

edit: pip show Telethon returns Location: `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages` while `python --version`is Python 3.11.6 so they seem to match up

edit 2: `>>> import sys; print(sys.path) ['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages']`

Comment: Sounds like your `pip` and `python3` commands are using different installations of python.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show Telethon`, specifically the `Location:` line

Comment: Also show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)` executed with `python3`

Comment: And please include those outputs directly in the question, not as separate comments.

Comment: @john-gordon , I did as you said.

Comment: Is this the Telethon Telegram package?

Comment: yes, It's the one used for the telegram client/telegram bots.

Comment: It's `telethon`, not `Telethon`. Your error message indicates you used a capital T instead of a lower-case t. Also, version 0.19.1.6 is from June 2018, which was then released with Python 3.6 as the latest version. Python 3.11 might work fine with it, but you should probably upgrade Telethon or downgrade Python.

Comment: thank you, that fixed the issue! the original creator must have been making a mistake, hence why it was Telethon and not telethon.

Comment: I would mark the question as answered, but stack overflow doesn't seem to allow comments to be marked as answers.